# How to get a list of objects with same objects property from an ArrayList by

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

How to retrieve a list of all the objects in an ArrayList with object property.

**Model Class:**

```
public class Item {
  private String id;
  private String name;
}
```

`ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList();`

Now, how can we search ArrayList with a particular name?

Eg: Get all the objects that have the name "Sam".

Comment: `items.stream().filter(item -> "Sam".equals(item.name)).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: Do you want to write an answer with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
List<Item> itemsNamedSam = items.stream()
    .filter(item -> item.name.equals("Sam"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Few notes:

- You should probably make the fields in `Item`- `private`. For example, as things stand you might accidentally reassign the `name` field.
- In most cases, we should work with `List<Item>` (interface), and not `ArrayList<Item>` (implementation).

Comment: Yes. Ok, I will change them to private. Is there any reason to use List instead of ArrayList and thanks for the help.

Comment: @Lenzman It's a principle in software engineering - resilience to change. Example 1: If in Java 18 there will be super-duper efficient implementation to the `List`, you will have to replace the `ArrayList` in many places instead of just the place you initialized the list. If you used some method that doesn't appear in the `List`, this will be even worse..

Comment: Example 2: requirements might change and you might not need to use `get(5)` but only to traverse the list in the order and add an item. In that case, `LinkedList` might be more suitable.

Comment: OK got it. Thanks Most Needed Rabbit

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @Alex's comment, What I ended up doing is:

```
 public static List<Item> findItemsByName(Collection<Item> listItems, String name) {
        
     return listItems.stream().filter(item -> name.equals(item.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove from a list all elements who doesn't have "Sam" name by using removeIf method:

```
itemsNamedSam.removeIf(item -> !item.name.equals("Sam"));
```